# Emitting event to clients during server shutdown in nodejs and socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am working on nodejs for client server functionality and using socket.io for emitting and receiving events. I am able to emit and receive events in my code but facing an issue in emitting and receiving an event during process shutdown. I want to emit an event to all clients during server(nodejs) shutdown. I am using it like this

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);                                                                                                              

process.on('SIGINT', shutdown);

function shutdown() {
  console.log('Inside shutdown server');
  //io.emit('shutdown', 'Server is going DOWN');
  io.sockets.emit('shutdown', 'Server is going DOWN');
  server.close(function () {
    console.log('closed express');   
  });    
  process.exit(0);
}
```

But shutdown event is not being received at other end. is there any thing I am missing here?

Code at receiving side:(nodejs)

```
socket.on('shutdown', function(msg) {
    console.log('inside shutdown ' + msg);
});
```

Please help me out in fixing this. 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Firstly is `io` declared in the file? If so you should not be doing `io.sockets.emit` but instead `io.emit` - I believe you should really be using the sockets instance and then calling `socket.broadcast.emit` that will send to all connected clients except for the sender

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the my question with the declaration part. I am able to emit and receive events in the same code but its not working in shutdown function as shown in the code. is there any restriction with process.on()?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, [socket.io](/questions/tagged/socket.io) handles sending messages in the [next tick](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback_args), so you must defer calling `process.exit(0)` to the next event loop iteration:

```
function shutdown() {
  // ...
  process.nextTick(() => {
    process.exit(0);
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried using process.nextTick() but still it is not getting received at other side.